# Intermittent lag followed by dead stop while editing

Tags: bug, documentation

(I'm reporting this per a conversation in chat. Please let me know if further information would be helpful.)

I've been experiencing slowdowns off and on all day while editing topics (all in the Lua section), and just now I had a tab become completely unresponsive for long enough that I had to just close it. The problem seemed to grow worse the longer the edit got. The initial smaller lags were anywhere from 2-5 seconds; definitely long enough to notice, but I could wait and then keep typing. Once the edit grew to somewhere over 2000 characters, these lags became more and more frequent and eventually the tab froze altogether. (I waited over a minute and then shut it.)
More details:

- Where: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/lua/676/tables/2258/iterating-tables#t=201607230015242510555
- OS X 10.10.5
- Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)
- Ghostery and uBlock Origin extensions were running. (As an experiment, I disabled these extensions, and the problem I mention in the next bullet point still occurs. That suggests that they extensions aren't the only problem, but I can't be sure one way or the other.)
- Something is definitely up still. When trying to file this bug report (in Chrome), I can't even visit the page in question. If I do, the browser tab hangs. I had to visit in Safari to get the URL.
- The post has a reasonable amount of Markdown (particularly lists and code blocks).
- Chrome itself is fine otherwise. Two other open tabs: Documentation's public chatroom and Twitter. Those tabs are ok.
- A follow-up: Safari was only ok on that page when I was *not* logged into SO. I didn't even realize at first, because I just wanted the URL. Once I logged in to edit, I had similar problems on Safari. No more editing for me tonight.

The good news is that contrary to what I thought, my preliminary work was saved (mostly?). Perhaps that's why when I go to that page it now goes wild: it's trying to call back the longish edit that was left hanging. I'm not sure about that either.

Comment: I think I'm encountering this too. The editing page seems to consume 100% of one core and totally freeze the page at random intervals while I'm typing, and for several seconds after. I'm editing 'introduction to matplotlib', with around 1,000 characters removed.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I was able to edit without trouble yesterday, but this morning, the problem is back in a big way. I had to quit trying to edit. It was too painful.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't noticed it until this morning. FWIW, I just added about 50 characters in another edit, and didn't have any freezes at all.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the length and complexity of the topic. Both times for me it was in a very long, multi-example topic. But I'm not sure.